# Full width code listing within two column text

Tags: listings, multicol

I am using `multicols` to create two columns for body text. For code typesetting I am using the `listings` package. For the latter I have created an environment using `\lstnewenvironment` command, used as `\begin{Code}..\end{Code}`. I would like the code to be typeset as **full width**.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
  ... two column text
  \begin{Code}...\end{Code}
  ... two column text
\end{multicols}
```

What I am after is to redefine the `Code` environment in such a way as to end the `multicols`, before it starts typesetting and re-start it at the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}         % prefer old tt font
\newcommand\emphasis[2][red]{\lstset{emph={write,void,writeln,#2},
   emphstyle={\ttfamily\textcolor{#1}}}}%
\lstnewenvironment{Code}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX}\lstset{%
      escapeinside={{(*@}{@*)}},
      breaklines=true,
      framesep=5pt,
      basicstyle=\ttfamily,
      showstringspaces=false,
      keywordstyle=\ttfamily\textcolor{blue},
      stringstyle=\color{orange},
     commentstyle=\color{black},
     rulecolor=\color{gray!10},
      breakatwhitespace=true,
     showspaces=false,  % shows spacing symbol
     xleftmargin=0pt,
     xrightmargin=5pt,
     aboveskip=0pt, % compact the code looks ugly in type
     belowskip=0pt,  % user responsible to insert any skips
      backgroundcolor=\color{gray!15}, #1
}}
{}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{Code}
  \def\somelongcommand{This is a test to demonstrate the problem}
\end{Code}
\lipsum[3]
\end{multicols}

Preferably,

\begin{Code}
  \def\somelongcommand{This is a test to demonstrate the problem}
\end{Code}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the package etoolbox with the special hooks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}         % prefer old tt font
\newcommand\emphasis[2][red]{\lstset{emph={write,void,writeln,#2},
   emphstyle={\ttfamily\textcolor{#1}}}}%
\lstnewenvironment{Code}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX}\lstset{%
      escapeinside={{(*@}{@*)}},
      breaklines=true,
      framesep=5pt,
      basicstyle=\ttfamily,
      showstringspaces=false,
      keywordstyle=\ttfamily\textcolor{blue},
      stringstyle=\color{orange},
     commentstyle=\color{black},
     rulecolor=\color{gray!10},
      breakatwhitespace=true,
     showspaces=false,  % shows spacing symbol
     xleftmargin=0pt,
     xrightmargin=5pt,
     aboveskip=0pt, % compact the code looks ugly in type
     belowskip=0pt,  % user responsible to insert any skips
      backgroundcolor=\color{gray!15}, #1
}}
{}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newtoggle{test:multicols}
\newcounter{savecolnum}
\AtBeginEnvironment{multicols}{%
   \global\toggletrue{test:multicols}
   }
\AtEndEnvironment{multicols}{%
 \global\setcounter{savecolnum}{\number\col@number}
 \global\togglefalse{test:multicols}
}


\BeforeBeginEnvironment{Code}{
   \iftoggle{test:multicols}%
      {\def\reserveda{\end{multicols}\global\toggletrue{test:multicols}}}
      {\let\reserveda\relax}
   \reserveda
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{Code}{%
   \iftoggle{test:multicols}%
      {\def\reserveda{\begin{multicols}{\thesavecolnum}}}
      {\let\reserveda\relax}
   \reserveda
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{Code}
  \def\somelongcommand{This is a test to demonstrate the problem}
\end{Code}
\lipsum[3]
\end{multicols}

Preferably,

\begin{Code}
  \def\somelongcommand{This is a test to demonstrate the problem}
\end{Code}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This worked very well with the minimal, but fails in the main document with no error. It typesets the code with no error, but still in two columns. You want to take a guess?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I would guess but I have no idea? Sorry ;-)

Comment: thanks, everything now works. Traced the error back to `\DefineShortVerb{\|}`, strange:(

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Some time ago I had the same problem with this shortverb and pstricks ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The package `etoolbox` comes to rescue: we have to evaluate the current environment *before* `\begin{Code}` is completely processed:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\multicols@string{multicols}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{Code}{%
  \ifx\@currenvir\multicols@string
    \xdef\resume@multicols{\noexpand\begin{multicols}{\number\col@number}}%
    \end{multicols}%
  \else
    \global\let\resume@multicols\@empty
  \fi}
\AfterEndEnvironment{Code}{\resume@multicols}
\makeatother
```

Of course you have to ensure that you don't issue `\begin{Code}` in the middle of another environment. Such a test might be implemented inside the `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` code, by issuing a warning.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have accepted Marco's as he went out of his way with a minimal. In the end I used a bit of combination from both.